# How to add multiple worksheet from different workbook to new workbook

Tags: c#, .net, excel, .net-core, microsoft.office.interop.excel

I have three excel files and by selecting cetain sheets from workbook want to create new worksheet

```
var App = new Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Application();

Workbook  book1 = App.Workbooks.Open(@"path");
Worksheet sheet1 = book1.Worksheets\[1\];

Workbook  book2 = App.Workbooks.Open(@"path");
Worksheet sheet2 = book2.Worksheets\[1\];

Workbook  book3 = App.Workbooks.Open(@"path");
Worksheet sheet3 = book3.Worksheets\[1\];

var newBook = App.Workbooks.Add();
sheet1.UsedRange.Copy(newBook.Worksheets[1].Range["A1"]);

---first sheet1 is adding perfectly but while adding second worksheet sheet2 it is throwing exception System.Runtime.InteropServices.COMException : Exception from HRESULT : 0x800401A8---

sheet2.UsedRange.Copy(newBook.Worksheets[2].Range["A1"]);
sheet3.UsedRange.Copy(newBook.Worksheets[3].Range["A1"]);
newBook.SaveAs(@"path\newWorkbook.xlsx");
newBook.Close();
App.Quit();

I already tried but same exception -
var sourceRange = sheet2.UsedRange; var targetRange = newBook.Worksheets[2].Range["A1"]; sourceRange.Copy(targetRange);
```

Comment: Are the files being opened in excel? Can you add a breakpoint and debug that the files are opened? Can you so it sequentially (Open1, copy1, paste1, close1) then the same for 2 and 3? If you change the order for 1 and 2, it works? In general, excel does not allow to open 2 files with the same name and your path is the same for the 3 files there. I guess that it could be that. Also, does the newBook has WorkSheet[2]? you should also check that.

Comment: No it is not working

Comment: What is not working? Can you please expand?

Comment: As already i provided in code comments when we add fisrt sheet into it easily added but when second sheet "sheet2" executes it throw's exception System.Runtime.InteropServices.COMException (On line no - 11 occuring excepition)

Comment: Does the `newBook` has `WorkSheet[2]`?

Comment: No it is programmically created completely new workbook also im open for different logic also just i want to add four sheet with data from different workbook into new one

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
var App = new Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Application();

Workbook  book1 = App.Workbooks.Open(@"path");
Worksheet sheet1 = book1.Worksheets\[1\];

Workbook  book2 = App.Workbooks.Open(@"path");
Worksheet sheet2 = book2.Worksheets\[1\];

Workbook  book3 = App.Workbooks.Open(@"path");
Worksheet sheet3 = book3.Worksheets\[1\];

var newBook = App.Workbooks.Add();

sheet1.Copy(newBook.Worksheets[1]);
sheet2.Copy(newBook.Worksheets[2]);
sheet3.Copy(newBook.Worksheets[3]);

//delete sheet which created by default while creating newBook
newBook.Worksheets[4].delete();

string path = @"path";
if(File.Exits(path))
{
File.Delete(path);
}
newBook.SaveAs(path);
book1.Close();
book2.Close();
book3.Close();
App.Quit();
```

Comment: Remember that Stack Overflow isn't just intended to solve the immediate problem, but also to help future readers find solutions to similar problems, which requires understanding the underlying code. This is especially important for members of our community who are beginners, and not familiar with the syntax. Given that, **can you [edit] your answer to include an explanation of what you're doing** and why you believe it is the best approach?